# How to correctly add a .resx file to an MVC 6 application.

Tags: localization, resources, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Using Visual Studio 2015 I can add a Resource File (Resource.resx) to an MVC 6 Project. However the modifier of the resource defaults to: Internal.

If I right click on the resource and select properties I cannot see any of the Advanced properties that I used to be able to see i.e. Browse to URL, Build Action, Copy to Output Directory, Custom Tool and Custom Tool Namespace. The only two properties I can see are the Misc ones i.e. File Name and Full Path.

If I open the resource by double clicking on it, the Access Modifier in Visual Studio is disabled.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Localization works a little differently in MVC6.

An example can be seen here: https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/tree/dev/samples/LocalizationSample.Web

One important note is that you have to run the application using: dnx web as there is a bug when running the application from visual studio. See this [issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/3846) for more information.